# Authentication error when I send email from Yandex using Flask

Tags: python, email, flask, flask-mail, yandex

I want to send emails from Yandex using Flask but I get "authentication failed: This user does not have access rights to this service".

I did this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request
from flask_mail import Mail, Message

app=Flask(__name__)
mail = Mail(app)

app.config['MAIL_SERVER'] = 'smtp.yandex.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 465
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = False
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'my-username@yandex.com'
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = 'my-password'
mail = Mail(app)


@app.route('/send-email')
def send_mail():
    msg = Message('This email was sent by me from Flask', sender='my-username@yandex.com',recipients=['rec@gmail.com'])
    msg.body = "This is the email body, I just wanted to test the flask email option, and see how doest it work."
    mail.send(msg)
    return 'Email sent!'
```

I was expecting the message to be sent, but I got the authentification error.
PS: My email and password are correct.

Comment: _My email and password are correct_ How do you know?  Have you verified them some other way?

Comment: @JohnGordon, I logged in my browser.

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback please?

Comment: @BcK, here you go: https://justpaste.it/8vm66